# Meteor delete list item with selected class

Tags: meteor

I am trying to add a delete function that if i click on a list item(template) it adds a selected class to the li. I then want be able to click a button that finds the li with a class of selected and passes the data to a meteor method that removes the data from a collection. How do i access this data.

I have tried a few ways but this is what i have so far.

**sidebar.js**

```
Template.Sidebar.events({
    'click .button-collapse': function() {
        console.log("here")
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
    },
    'click #delete i': function() {
        Meteor.call('deleteListItem', $( "li.selected" )._id);
    }
})
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<template name="Sidebar">
<ul id="slide-out" class="side-nav fixed grey darken-3">
    <li class="action-bar">
        <span id="add-new" data-target="modal-add" class="modal-trigger"><i class="small material-icons">add</i></span>
        <span id="save"><i class="small material-icons">note_add</i></span>
        <span id="rename"><i class="small material-icons">mode_edit</i></span>
        <span id="delete"><i class="small material-icons">delete</i></span>
        <span data-activates="slide-out" id="close" class="button-collapse close "><i class="small material-icons right">reorder</i></span>
    </li>
    <!-- Load save items-->
    {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
        {{#each userSaves}}
            {{>ListItem}}
        {{/each}}
    {{else}}
        <p>Loading</p>
    {{/if}}
</ul>
<a href="#" data-activates="slide-out" style="display:none" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
<!-- Modal form to add new simulator file -->
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal-add" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>New Simulator</h4>
        {{> quickForm collection=saves id="newSimulator" type="insert" buttonClasses="modal-action modal-close btn waves-effect waves-light" buttonContent="Add"}}
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

**list class**

```
Meteor.methods({
    deleteListItem: function(id) {
        Saves.remove(id);
    }
});
```

Comment: again, I'm telling you to post ALL your related codes. you left out ListItem Template again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not retrieve the ID of an object like that. Either your button has to be inside the document you're gonna remove or you have to include the `_id` in your HTML attributes and get that value.

So simply add `data-value="{{_id}}"` to your `<li>` in your loop and get the selected like this:

```
//this will retrieve the id of one selected element only
//you need to use each/forEach if you want to remove multiple
$('li.selected').attr('data-value')
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution would be using `Session`. Since you click on an item to select it, you can set a `Session` in that event

```
//in the click event where you select a list item
Session.set('itemId', this._id);

//in Sidebar events
'click #delete i': function() {
    const itemId = Session.get('itemId');
    Meteor.call('deleteListItem', itemId);
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you use Session solution, don't forget to remove the Session when the template is destroyed. Otherwise (for your use case) when you go to another route and come back without deleting a selected item and click the delete button, it will delete the document even though it doesn't appear to be selected.

```
Template.templateName.onDestroyed(function(){
    Session.set('sessionName', undefined);
});
```

Comment: Can I ask you why did you use a const

Comment: @AmyTeresaHyland because its a constant value. we're not changing it later